# Viewing parts of a HTML page?

Tags: android

My first Q :D

Situation:
I want to view parts of a website. Example http://epguides.com/dexter and look at the sourcecode. :

`<div id="eplist">`
`<pre>`
**I want to show this**
`<pre>`

I'd love to post my code.. But so far I've tested xml parsing, JSON and so on without any luck.

Any of you pro's have a tip? :D

Solved: 
`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://epguides.com/dexter").get();`
`Elements episodes = doc.select("#eplist pre");`
`String epHTML = episodes.html();`
Streetcreds to Mubix :D

Random thoughts:
It's really slow, that goes for my "latest twitterpost getter" too.
Not sure how this will work if your not on WIFI, but I guess isn't the best way to go. Anyone smart comments on this?

Next "problem":
How can you view the result with the same layout as the original page?
(As if you just cropped the site)

Thanks for all the respons :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for screen scraping. Here's a simple example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://epguides.com/dexter").get();
Elements episodes = doc.select("#eplist pre");
String epHTML = episodes.html();
```

**P.S.**: You should consider extracting the data on a server and then passing it to the android app. Otherwise, users would have to download a new version everytime the site changes it's format.

Comment: !
Dunno what to say. U made my day :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML parsing (check the doctype or the returned document), or use, for example, jQuery to leave only the interesting part on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get pages with dynamicly url, you can't get it becauese of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), so you have to do it with a proxy. For example you can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) or write your own proxy with php([curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).

[How to make cross domain request using ajax or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988966/how-to-make-cross-domain-request-using-ajax-or-javascript)